# Bootstrap modal displays grey background

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

I am trying to display a modal in an accordion but whenever I click on the modal button, the screen becomes grey and the modal ends up not showing.

This is my code:

```
@if(isset($data))
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    @foreach($data as $datum)
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#{{$datum['id']}}">
                {{ucfirst($datum['username'])}}</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="{{$datum['id']}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Current balance: {{$datum['wallet']['balance']}} <br>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{$datum['id']}}">Transfer</button>
                <!-- Modal -->
                <div id="{{$datum['id']}}" class="modal fade in" role="dialog" >
                    <div class="modal-dialog">

                        <!-- Modal content-->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Transfer Funds</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <label>Amount</label>
                                    <input type="number" name="amount" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount to be transferred">
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" name="sub_agent" value="{{$datum['username']}}">

                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the same `id="{{$datum['id']}}"` for multiple HTML elements on your page:

```
<div id="{{$datum['id']}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
...
  <div id="{{$datum['id']}}" class="modal fade in" role="dialog">
```

Which means that these toggles:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#{{$datum['id']}}">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{$datum['id']}}">Transfer</button>
```

Don't know what to target. Remember: **in HTML, `id` attributes must be unique.**

Try changing to the following:

```
<div id="{{$datum['id']}}_collapse" class="panel-collapse collapse">
...
  <div id="{{$datum['id']}}_modal" class="modal fade in" role="dialog">
```

And adjust your targeting elements to:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#{{$datum['id']}}_collapse">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#{{$datum['id']}}_modal">Transfer</button>
```